# Make a Single Word in a String All CAPS (when returned from database) - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

Is there a way to make a single word in a string all CAPS.  The field is being returned from the database by a form.  For example, I want "Jane is the BEST programmer" for the string "jane is the best programmer".

EDIT: In the view: `<%= @sentence.capitalize %>` `"hello".gsub!('best','BEST')` - first response below - doesn't work with that.  While this question got tagged as 'regex' by Stackoverflow, it's a rails application.

(And, yes, if I save "Jane is the BEST programmer" to the database and return it without `titleize` or `capitalize`, I do get "Jane is the BEST programmer".  However, this is just an example.  In the actual use case, all data / strings are converted to lower case before save. We want to capitalize some keywords for display purposes.)

`titleize` gives me `Jane Is The Best Programmer`

`capitalize` gives me `Jane is the best programmer`

A work-around to get `Jane is the BEST programmer` is?

Perhaps, parse the string and re-assemble it in the view?  Although I'd rather do it in the model layer.  Something like `%w{ keyword }.upcase`  The alternative, I suspect is using a complex regular expression - which I'd rather avoid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you find and replace the word(lower case to upcase)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this would be to replace the lower case version with the capitalized case of the word. You could do it with code similar to the code below.

```
sentence.gsub! 'best', 'BEST'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10835652)

Comment: How is replacing the string with the capitalized version of the string not answer the question ?

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...) the "something like this should work" is more a comment to test something

Comment: The phrase jane is the best programmer is being returned by `<%= @sentence.capitalize %>` in the view. I'll edit the original question to note that. Your recommendation works for a string, e.g.`"hello".gsub!('hello','HELLO')`, but doesn't work for `<%= @sentence.capitalize.gsub!('hello','HELLO') %>` or `"<%= @sentence.capitalize %>".gsub!('hello','HELLO')` an alternative I tried.  This is the kind of simple solution I'm looking for; however, I don't think it works for my use case.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this. Say you have model `Profile`

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

# attributes: id, about1, about2, ... etc.

# pretty much alias about1
def sentence1
  emphasize(about1)
end

private
def emphasize(sentence)
  keywords = %w{best awesome great}
  keywords.each do |w|
    re = /\b(#{w})\b/i
    if about1.match(re)  
      sentence.gsub!(re, w.upcase)
    end
  end 
  sentence
end
```

where `about1` is `jane is the best programmer` and you use `sentence1` instead.

It's not the prettiest, nor the most performant, but it should work.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  `about1` is - as edited in my original question - actually `@sentence.capitalize`  - which is the title of a view and changes based upon which record is called.  So (thinking out loud), I need to make `about1` a variable.  I'll work on that later today and let you know what works.  Thanks

Comment: I've tried a number of variations of your code without success.  Intriguingly, I can't even raise an error - and I tried using the code (and variants) in the model and controller.  I'm going to be attending a Meetup this weekend that some pretty experienced rubyists attend.  I'll let you know what we figure out.  Thanks, Doug

Comment: If you want to shoot me an email I can probably help you through it! My email is in my profile.

Comment: Josh - Thanks; however, I'd like to let the ChicagoRuby Meetup have a go at it.  It's the kind of problem the experience programmers like.  I'm just surprised there's not a built in method.  While I posted this as a title string issue, it's also about individual's degrees, i.e., having electrical engineer display as EE rather than Ee.